# HOw do I suppress the VIsual Basic "Macros are Disabled" Dialog that shows when opening a word doc in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, automation, ms-office

I have a really annoying problem.

I am openign a word document via c# / COM Interop (Word 2007).  I want to prevent the Macros from Running as some of them may crash (older files with missing bookmarks etc.).

So I run the following code to suppress all the dialogs that may pop up:

```
Word.ApplicationClass wordApplication = new Word.ApplicationClass();

wordApplication.DisplayAlerts = Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

wordApplication.ShowVisualBasicEditor = false;

wordApplication.AutomationSecurity = 
  Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

Word.Document wordDoc = null;
```

When I then execute the following code, I get the message box "Macros in this Project are Disabled".

```
 wordDoc = wordApplication.Documents.Open(
                ref paramSourceDocPath, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
                ref paramMissing);
```

I need to either suppress this message, dettect if it is being shown and "ok" it or find a way of disableing startup macros without VB getting in the way.

Any Ideas?

Comment: just wanted to follow up to see if the below answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I never could get this to work with C#, but with VB.NET it was fine. Here's how to do it: [How to open document that contains AutoOpen macro with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846407/how-to-open-document-that-contains-autoopen-macro-with-powershell/3206081#3206081)

Comment: Todd, it's been a few years since this answer. Is there anything new that you know of that would work in C#?

Comment: @arbitrarystringofletters Unfortunately, no. Office programming continues to work better/easier for VB/VBA. I guess C# gets all the glory everywhere else, but in Office, VB.NET still rules.

Answer (score -1):

[This article](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/InterDev/DisableAutoMacros.htm) might help.  I'm not sure how you'd translate it to C#.

VBA code:

```
WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 1   ' Disables auto macros
WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros 0   ' Enables auto macros
```

I don't know if this will disable the "Macros in this Project are Disabled" message.