# disable macro when opening word documents using office interop apis

Tags: interop, macros, dialog, ms-office

hi
how to disable macros when opening documents using office interop apis. I am currently using office 2007.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're automating using VB.NET, it's quite easy - see this thread for an example of `DisableAutoMacros`: [How to open document that contains AutoOpen macro with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846407/how-to-open-document-that-contains-autoopen-macro-with-powershell). I was never able to figure out how to do this in C# though.